# Interpreting escape characters in a string read from user input

Tags: string, rust, escaping, newline

I am writing a small CLI app in Rust. It processes user input, and if a special escape character is found, it needs to be interpreted.

For example, if user inputs a string `'New\nLine'`, it should be interpreted as:
New
Line

This is my code so far

```rust
fn main() {
    let text: Vec<String> = vec![String::from(r"New\n"), 
                                 String::from(r"Line")];
    slash_parser(text);
}


fn slash_parser(text: Vec<String>) {
    let mut text = text.join(" ");
    println!("{}", text); // ---> New\n Line
    if text.contains("\\") {
        text = str::replace(&text, r"\n", r"\\n");
        println!("{}", text); // ---> New\\n Line
        println!("New\nLine") // ---> New
                              // ---> Line
    }
}
```

I thought adding an extra `\` to the string will make it be interpreted as new line, but I was clearly mistaken.

For some reason if a string in passed as an argument it's interpreted as a string without special characters.
But if string is printed as string literal, then the `\n` symbol is interpreted as new line.

What am I understanding here wrong, and how to make that `\n` in a string be interpreted as a new line?

Comment: Just do `"\n"`?

Comment: @Dogbert you mean like this: ```text = str::replace(&text, "\\n", "\\\\n");``` ?  
I tried that, still the same :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how escaping in string literals works.

The quick answer is:

- `text` already has the newline character in it, as you construct the string wrong. I think you meant `"New\\n"` or `r"New\n"`.
- to replace `'\'` and `'n'` with the newline character, do: `text = str::replace(&text, "\\n", "\n");`.

---

### Background: String literals and escaping

The string literal `"New\nLine"` does **not** contain the characters `'\'` and `'n'`. `\n` is a single character, the `\` here is a so called [escape character](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std/str.html#literals-and-escapes) that allows for the creation of special characters. Like the newline character `\n`:

```rust
let s = "New\nLine";
println!("{:?}", s.chars().collect::<Vec<_>>());
println!("{}", s);
```

```
['N', 'e', 'w', '\n', 'L', 'i', 'n', 'e']
New
Line
```

But if the user enters it, it most definitely is the two characters `\` and `n`. To create a string literal that actually contains those two characters, you have to *escape* the `\` as otherwise `\n` would be interpreted as a single character:

```rust
let s = "New\\nLine";
println!("{:?}", s.chars().collect::<Vec<_>>());
println!("{}", s);
```

```
['N', 'e', 'w', '\\', 'n', 'L', 'i', 'n', 'e']
New\nLine
```

Note that the `\` character is here shown as `\\`. In representations that allow escaping, `\\` is used for representing an actual `\` character.

Alternatively, you could create a [raw string literal](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std/str.html#literals-and-escapes) which does not perform escaping; meaning, what you see is actually what you get:

```rust
let s = r#"New\nLine"#;
println!("{:?}", s.chars().collect::<Vec<_>>());
println!("{}", s);
```

```
['N', 'e', 'w', '\\', 'n', 'L', 'i', 'n', 'e']
New\nLine
```

---

### The actual question: interpreting user strings

So if we get a user string, it most certainly does *not* contain the `\n` character, but instead the two characters `\` and `n`. So let's use the raw string `r#"New\nLine"` to represent the user input.

Now we can simply replace the `'\'` and `'n'` characters with the special character `'\n'`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let s = r#"New\nLine"#;

    let s_unescaped = s.replace("\\n", "\n");

    println!("User input:\n{}\n", s);
    println!("Unescaped:\n{}", s_unescaped);
}
```

```
User input:
New\nLine

Unescaped:
New
Line
```

With `.replace("\\n", "\n")`, we replace the string `"\\n"`, which is the characters `\` and `n`, with `"\n"`, which is the newline character.

Of course instead of `"\\n"` we could write the raw string `r"\n"`:

```rust
let s_unescaped = s.replace(r"\n", "\n");
```

---

### Additional remarks

A lot of confusion also arises from the fact that `Display` (`{}`) and `Debug` (`{:?}`) print strings differently. While `{}` prints it in its unescaped form (meaning newlines actually get printed as line breaks), the `{:?}` *escapes* the string before printing it:

```rust
fn main() {
    let s = "New\nLine";
    println!("{}", s);
    println!("{:?}", s);

    println!("---");

    let s = "New\\nLine";
    println!("{}", s);
    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

```
New
Line
"New\nLine"
---
New\nLine
"New\\nLine"
```

Comment: Wow, this just blew my tiny mind! 
Especially the part about ```\n``` being a single character, it makes so much sense now...
Thanks for such a great reply!!!